# Deployed ASP.Net Web API Return Value Not Updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, deployment

I created a Web API that will get data from database and return it in json format. For example I have 2 records in my database and call the web api it returns the 2 records but when I added new data to my database it did not show the result. but when I run it locally the 3 records displayed. In order for me to see the 3 records in my deployed api I need to REBUILD and DEPLOY again. Does anyone have an experience like this? How did you solve this problem?

```
public class ContactRepository : IContactRepository
{
    private List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
    private string ContactId;
    string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

    public ContactRepository()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ContactId, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Mobile FROM sysdba.CONTACT WHERE LASTNAME LIKE 'R%' AND FIRSTNAME LIKE 'R%' AND EMAIL <> '' ORDER BY CreateDate DESC, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME", conn))
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    ContactId = dr[0].ToString();
                    Add(new Contact { Name = dr[1].ToString() + " " + dr[2].ToString(), Email = dr[3].ToString(), MobileNo = dr[4].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAll()
    {
        return Contacts;
    }
}

interface IContactRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> GetAll();
    Contact Get(string id);
    Contact Add(Contact contact);
    void Remove(string id);
    bool Update(Contact contact);
}

public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IContactRepository repository = new ContactRepository();

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContact()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is happening because you are creating static instance of ContactRepository in Controller. So it will created only once. So ultimately `ContactRepository` constructor will be called only once.

I can see that `getAll()` returns contact list which is being filled in the constructor.

> > In order for me to see the 3 records in my deployed api I need to REBUILD and DEPLOY again.

The problem is with the static instance so there is no need to redeploy. Restarting IIS would also get you the expected result.

So making ContactRepository non static in constructor would resolve your issue.

But this would cause sql query to be executed every  time you create a new instance so better approch to this is you move logic from constructor to `GetAll()` method in `ContactRepository`.

Comment: Thank you for helping man, it works. You save my day. Im new to this frame work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `ContactController` has a static member for `ContactRepository`, and the only time you query the database for contacts is within the constructor for `ContactRepository`.

This static initialization happens exactly once, upon the first request, and subsequent requests will always return the same list of contacts.

You should either change your member to be non-static so that a new repository instance is created for each controller instance, or change your repository `GetAll` method to perform a query each time.